# Polymer Second Paper Drawer

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element

i need a second paper drawer on the right side of my site.
Is this possible with polymer 1 and the paper-drawer element?
have anyone a code sample for me?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Relevant docs: [Polymer `paper-drawer-panel` element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel)

Comment: hey, thank you! i read the docs, but my problem isn't that i cant place the paper-drawer on the right side of my site. i need a second one to put content into it.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know Polymer. I was just linking to the docs to save time for other answerers who know Polymer but don’t remember how `paper-drawer-panel` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep using elements by Google, you can use app-layout's [`app-drawer-layout`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-drawer-layout), they even have a [2 drawer demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?view=demo:app-drawer-layout/demo/two-drawers.html&active=app-drawer-layout) so you can view its [source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-drawer-layout/demo/two-drawers.html) for an example

Answer (score 1):

Polymer's [`paper-drawer-panel`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel) does not support more than one drawer, but you could use a third-party element for that: [`paper-multidrawer-panel`](https://github.com/WoodyWoodsta/paper-multidrawer-panel).

```
<paper-multidrawer-panel>
  <paper-header-panel left-drawer>...</paper-header-panel>
  <paper-header-panel right-drawer>...</paper-header-panel>
  <paper-header-panel main>...</paper-header-panel>
</paper-multidrawer-panel>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KMNmdy?editors=1000)

For future reference, I recommend searching https://customelements.io for any elements you might need. The search results include Polymer's own elements as well as those contributed by the community.

Comment: You beat me to it again :). But yes, the `paper-multidrawer-panel` is great!

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz :) I agree

Comment: I recommend the 2-drawer `app-drawer-layout` from Alan's answer, although the end result is slightly different than the one in `paper-multidrawer-layout`.

Answer (score 1):

Just nest the drawers?

```
  <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow drawer-toggle-attribute="d1" class="fit">
    <div drawer>
      <!-- Left drawer here -->

    </div>
    <div main class="fit">
      <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow right-drawer drawer-toggle-attribute="d2" class="fit">
        <div drawer>
          <!-- Right drawer here -->

        </div>
        <div main class="fit">

          <!-- Main contents go here -->
          <h1>Left-drawer toggle</h1>
          <paper-icon-button d1 icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
          <h1>Right-drawer toggle</h1>
          <paper-icon-button d2 icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>

        </div>
      </paper-drawer-panel>
    </div>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qocuyurazi/edit?html,output

Comment: Neat solution. This seems to achieve the same effect (mostly) as the 2-drawer `app-drawer-layout` that Alan points out.